# <any> in enum with string in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have come over the following snippets to support enum with string

```
enum Color {
    red = <any>"red", green = <any>"green", Blue = <any>"blue"
}
```

What is the  means and why we need it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the means

Typescript Enums are only `number`s. So if you assign a string the compiler will complain.

```
enum Color {
    red = "red" // error `string` is not assignable to color
}
```

But by using `any` you are telling the compiler **shhhh... I know better**. [More on this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html).

Note: If you do this you will potentially need to shhhhh the compiler again e.g. :

```
enum Color {
    red = <any>"red" // shhhh
}

var foo = Color.red; // okay
foo = 123; // okay: TypeScript still thinks red is a number  
foo = "red"; // Error
foo = <any>"red"; // shhhhh
```

## What an assertion really is

[image]

## Alternate string based enums

> why we need it

If you want string based enums. I personally use this pattern right now : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/stringEnums.html

And with typescript 1.8 there will be *first class support* e.g.

```
type Foo = "a" | "b";
```